# where store challenge questions in WSO2 Identity server by tenant?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I add some challenge query questions to any challenge query set, but i don't find them that where is stored. I search any Table in DB but did not exist anywhere.

Can you please help out or describe an way of find store location them ?

Thank you very much, Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is saved in the registry.

You login to management console as tenant admin. Go to Main -> Registry -> Browse and browse the resources at path `/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/questionCollection`.

See the properties of the resources for the details.